# mac OSX Unknown pseudo-op: .type

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, gcc4.4

I have to write some assembler code. Therefore I installed gcc4.4 (per homebrew) and called `gcc-4.4 -c asma.s`, but it does not work as expected:

```
asma.s:3:Unknown pseudo-op: .type
asma.s:3:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 97 (a).
```

The first lines consist only of standard pseudo-ops!

```
    .text
    .globl asma
    .type asma, @function
asma:
```

Do I have to install an alternative assembler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.type` is an `ELF`/`COFF` directive, while OSX uses `Mach-O` format. In most cases you can safely remove the line.